# Language detection using tesseract or abby ocr

Tags: ocr, tesseract, language-detection, abbyy

I have images of document containing either arabic or english text as image is it possible somehow to know what language out of this two an image contain

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to the site!  The question you ask is a bit too broad for StackOverflow's Q&A style.  Highly recommend you read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (if you haven't, yet)

Comment: I don't see what's unclear of this question and why it's voted for closing. It's basically asking for language auto-detection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You set two possible recognition languages ("English", "Arabic"), then do OCR and check the recognized text character set. Latinic alphabet will indicate English.

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: For Tesseract: tesseract -l eng -l ara /input.jpg /output.pdf pdf

Comment: tesseract 250ed54bc7a2dba6ea53e80c3fdd5192.jpg outputfile -l eng+rus